# Can not start the Virtual Machine No KVM Installed

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Ok so my Server Crashed Y'day. So I bought a another WS and plug in the HDD's. Booted up did very little changes and everything was working fine EXCEPT!!! the Virtual Machines inside VMM and the VM Player does not come up.  VMM gives me an error when I try to boot up the VM's here it is,

```
Error starting domain: internal error Process exited while reading console log output: char device redirected to /dev/pts/1
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
No accelerator found!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 45, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 66, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1120, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 551, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: internal error Process exited while reading console log output: char device redirected to /dev/pts/1
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
No accelerator found!
```

So far this is what I have done

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bn bridge-utils virt-manager

virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------

sudo apt-get install kvm ubuntu-vm-builder libvirt-bin bridge-utils
```

and rebooted the server and fired up the VMM but same error.:(

```
egrep -c '(svm|vmx)' /proc/cpuinfo

8
```

When I run `ls -l /dev/kvm` it give me

```
cannot access /dev/kvm: No such file or directory

# rmmod kvm_intel

ERROR: Module kvm_intel does not exist in /proc/modules
```

I am really stuck with this as the ERP SW is running in a VM on VMM and a Virtual Secondary DC is running on VMPlayer.  The primary DC is shooting replication errors everywhere... Please help anyone???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After couple of hrs and 2 days of troubleshooting.... VMware threw me the answer.  It was right in front of me... The solution to the KVM issue I got was simple modification in Bios.  The Vt-x need to be enabled and Execution Prevention should be disabled.... Both VMM and VM Player is working fine.  However  I have to restore the VM's from the Back up as it was corrupted.  Apart from that... all is working fine..... So Far... :)

Thank you guys.....

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add yourself to the appropriate groups:

- Add the required user to the libvirtd and kvm groups:

  sudo usermod -a -G libvirtd,kvm <username>
- REBOOT. Logging out and back in does NOT suffice due to kvm module
  permissions handling. Reboot.

Also, your description is a bit unclear on this, but you can't use two hypervisors that require hardware virtualization at the same time, as the CPU can only serve one of these. E.g. if you're running virtualbox (or maybe VMware - I'm unfamiliar with it so I don't know) then kvm won't start. If you are, try stopping VMware and try running kvm again.